# Clear session cookies in ie11?

Tags: internet-explorer-11

in previous versions of IE the F12 dev tools had several option for cache and cookie management, but in the new IE 11 version (on the network tab) the option to clear / delete session cookies seems to be missing, does anyone know where to find it, (or how to accomplish this)

ps- no, "close IE and restart" is not a solution

Comment: You'll surely get better help on http://superuser.com/ which is intended (except other) for general computer software questions. StackOverflow is primarily intended for programming questions. Feel free to delete this question from here and ask it on http://superuser.com/ (if it's possible). Thanks, and welcome aboard! :-)

Comment: `How do I do {x} with the developer tools` seems like a valid SO question.

Answer (score 46):

There's a *Clear Cookies for Domain* button at the top center of the Network tab in the remodeled F12 tools.

To clear ALL session cookies, in the address bar, type:

`javascript:document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache")`

and hit enter. Note that you **must** type this command yourself; if you copy/paste it, IE will delete the `javascript:` at the front of the string for security reasons.

Comment: Any ideas how to clear cookies for particular domain in IE 11?

Comment: @Vipresh That is answered in the very first line of my answer. But please don't use comments to ask questions.

Comment: Oh yaa I realized that after a bit more googling, but that wont help me as my network tab freezes IE every time I click on it.I will create a new question about that issue.

Comment: I was able to use this in QTP with "javascript:document.execCommand(" & chr(34) & "ClearAuthenticationCache" & chr(34) & ")" and Browser.Navigate to clear cache and log back in without creating new session, thank you

Answer (score 9):

Press F12 to open Developer Tools, go to Console tab, enter this Javascript command

```
document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache")
```

I tried and saw that typing in address bar won't work.

Comment: Typing in the address bar works just fine. You cannot `paste` it in the address bar due to this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/19/socially-engineered-xss-attacks-and-pasting-javascript-in-the-address-bar-in-ie9.aspx